# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

Input:
`pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2015-06-01'),axis=0)`

Output:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-f9b333cfd215> in <module>()
----> 1 pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2015-06-01'),axis=0)
      2 pred_ci = pred.conf_int()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py in get_prediction(self, start, end, dynamic, index, exog, **kwargs)
   1924         # Handle start, end, dynamic
   1925         _start, _end, _out_of_sample, prediction_index = (
-> 1926             self.model._get_prediction_index(start, end, index, silent=True))
   1927 
   1928         # Handle exogenous parameters

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py in _get_prediction_index(self, start, end, index, silent)
    475         # indexes.
    476         try:
--> 477             start, start_index, start_oos = self._get_index_label_loc(start)
    478         except KeyError:
    479             raise KeyError('The `start` argument could not be matched to a'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py in _get_index_label_loc(self, key, base_index)
    410         try:
    411             loc, index, index_was_expanded = (
--> 412                 self._get_index_loc(key, base_index))
    413         except KeyError as e:
    414             try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py in _get_index_loc(self, key, base_index)
    351             # RangeIndex)
    352             try:
--> 353                 index[key]
    354             # We want to raise a KeyError in this case, to keep the exception
    355             # consistent across index types.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    496 
    497         if is_scalar(key):
--> 498             n = int(key)
    499             if n != key:
    500                 return super_getitem(key)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: What is `results`?  Tell us why you think this method will accept a timestamp as argument.

Comment: I am using time series model (ARIMA) in order to get prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Use a python datetime or string rather than a pandas datetime64:

```py
results.get_prediction(start='2015-06-01', axis=0)
# or
import datetime as dt
results.get_prediction(start=dt.datetime(2015, 6, 1), axis=0)
```

Should work here.

*See [the docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.get_prediction.html).*

Comment: I have tried this and got this error.   `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' `

Comment: @ShriDharani with the first version (string) too?